# dylib seems not working to be imported in Java

Tags: java, dylib

I'm trying to load some dylib in my java code. the system load is rejecting them but the dylib are imported in the project as shown on the pic below :

[image]

I loading the lib as below

package desktop;

```
public class desktop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.loadLibrary("libiamusb-compat");
        System.loadLibrary("libiamusb1");
        System.loadLibrary("liblibiammtp");

    }

}
```

the issue is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libiamusb-compat in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at i.am.desktop.desktop.main(desktop.java:7)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: How are you running your Java program?  Are you using Maven?

Comment: I'm using eclipse and that's it. with the basic jre path

Comment: Please review [this page](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-MacOSX.asp) and then come back here if you cannot resolve it yourself.  There is a bit of configuration you need to do to get `dylib` working.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen still facing the issue even when I set the static path instead of relative one/